# How can i modify the height of input textfield in login form in drupal 7?

Tags: theming

how can i costumize a form ( for example login form ) in /user and specifically the height of input textfield? And the button "login"?
I try with the function theme_form_element() but nothing good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.form-submit is for the submit button.

textfield

```
#my-form input {

}
```

text area

```
#my-form textarea {

}
```

form selects

```
#my-form select {

}
```

submit button

```
#my-form .form-submit {

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this, is with CSS

An example could be:

```
.form-submit {
  height: 30px;
 }
```

You can't set height on textfields and submit buttons AFAIK, only text areas.

Comment: Is not too much generic operate in class .form-submit?

Comment: @Giovanni B. It's an example to show of how simple the css code needed is. Since all forms (and input fields) have a unique HTML ids, you can use that to style only the element you want.

Comment: Ok googletorp but when i modify a input,textarea adding for example a max width of 300px, this property is adding also for example in the users block that is positioned in front page and i dont want it.